# What wtpversion value to use?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3, eclipse-wtp

In one article I have seen this instruction to convert a Maven project to a dynamic web Eclipse project:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=1.5
```

So, what does it mean **wtpversion** and its value **1.5**? What wtpversion value should I use with Eclipse Indigo and jdk 1.7.0?

Comment: Additional information can be found here: [WTP support](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/wtp.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WTP adds web application support to Eclipse. You should use WTP version 2.0

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

Comment: but how can i know that which version i have installed and should it be compatible with it?